# JQuery click event only working first time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I am trying to make a dial pad just for the heck of it, the only problem I have ran into so far is that when a key is clicked it will put the corresponding number in the input box, but it won't put another one after that. I have looked at a lot of other posts, because other people have the same problem, but it seems that none of those solutions relate to my problem. Thanks in advance!

**The "1" button is the only one I have functioning right now because I am waiting to implement the others until I fix my problem.**

---

```
var inp = $('#dialer');
var nmbr = inp.val();
var key1 = $('#111');

key1.on('click', function(){
  inp.val(nmbr + 1)
});
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a4suk0rs/

Comment: It will help if you learn some basic debugging techniques.  In this case, add a simple `alert(nmbr);` inside the click event.  This will confirm whether the click event is firing or not.  It's one problem it not firing and another it not doing what you're expecting.  You can also use `console.log(nmbr)` if you know how to use the console (press F11...).

Comment: Yes very late but I have to say it , you need to get value of `nmbr` number again when you click on button

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you're setting `var nmbr = inp.val();` only once, so that variable will only ever contain the elements' initial value. Change your code to this:

```
var inp = $('#dialer');
var nmbr = inp.val();
var key1 = $('#111');

key1.on('click', function(){
  nmbr = inp.val(); // reset the `nmbr` var to the current value of `$('#dialer')`
  inp.val(nmbr + 1)
});
```

Comment: Wow great thinking, I don't know if I ever would have caught that.